# Combining two scripts [ Mirroring the webcam ]

Tags: python, opencv, mirror, mediapipe, cvzone

Dear friends in Stack overflow, I have problems in combining these two scripts in my virtual Keyboard project. The project is based on Python 3 and OpenCV. Please help.

Details of import

CVZone 1.41

Mediapipe 0.88

Script 1:

```
import cv2
from time import sleep
import mediapipe as mp
from cvzone.HandTrackingModule import HandDetector
import numpy as np
import cvzone



detector = HandDetector(detectionCon=0.8)
keys = [["Q", "W", "E", "R", "T", "Y", "U", "I", "O", "P"],
        ["A", "S", "D", "F", "G", "H", "J", "K", "L", ";"],
        ["Z", "X", "C", "V", "B", "N", "M", ",", ".", "/"]]

finalText = ""
# def drawALL(img, buttonList):
#
#     for button in buttonList:
#         x, y = button.pos
#         w, h = button.size
#         cv2.rectangle(img, button.pos, (x + w, y + h), (255, 0, 255), cv2.FILLED)
#         cv2.putText(img, button.text, (x + 20, y + 65),
#                      cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 4, (255, 255, 255), 4)
#     return img


def drawAll(img, buttonList):
    imgNew = np.zeros_like(img, np.uint8)
    for button in buttonList:
        x, y = button.pos
        cvzone.cornerRect(imgNew, (button.pos[0], button.pos[1], button.size[0], button.size[1]),
                          20, rt=0)
        cv2.rectangle(imgNew, button.pos, (x + button.size[0], y + button.size[1]),
                      (255, 0, 255), cv2.FILLED)
        cv2.putText(imgNew, button.text, (x + 40, y + 60),
                    cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 2, (255, 255, 255), 3)

    out = img.copy()
    alpha = 0.5
    mask = imgNew.astype(bool)
    print(mask.shape)
    out[mask] = cv2.addWeighted(img, alpha, imgNew, 1 - alpha, 0)[mask]
    return out

class Button():
    def __init__(self,pos,text,size=[85,85]):
        self.pos = pos
        self.size = size
        self.text = text


buttonList =[]

for i in range(len(keys)):
    for j, key in enumerate(keys[i]):
        buttonList.append(Button([100 * j + 50, 100 * i + 50], key))

video = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
video.set(3, 1280)
video.set(4, 720)

while True:

    success, img = video.read()
    img = detector.findHands(img)
    lmList, bboxInfo = detector.findPosition(img)
    img = drawAll(img, buttonList)

    if lmList:
        for button in buttonList:
            x,y = button.pos
            w,h = button.size

            if x< lmList[8][0] <x+w and y<lmList[8][1]<y+h:
                cv2.rectangle(img, button.pos, (x + w, y + h), (175, 0, 175), cv2.FILLED)
                cv2.putText(img, button.text, (x + 20, y + 65),
                            cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 4, (255, 255, 255), 4)
                l,_,_ = detector.findDistance(8,12,img,draw=False)
                print(l)
                if l<30:
                    cv2.rectangle(img, button.pos, (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), cv2.FILLED)
                    cv2.putText(img, button.text, (x + 20, y + 65),
                                cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 4, (255, 255, 255), 4)
                    finalText += button.text
                    sleep(0.25)
    cv2.rectangle(img, (50,350), (700,450), (175, 0, 175), cv2.FILLED)
    cv2.putText(img, finalText, (60, 435),
                cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN,5 , (255, 255, 255), 5)
    cv2.imshow("Image",img)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
```

For script 1, the program is working but the webcam shows inverted output. It shows opposite direction of my hand movement.

For script 2:

```
class Mirror:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__setupCamera()
        # If you have problems running this code on MacOS X you probably have to reinstall opencv
        # with qt backend because cocoa support seems to be broken:
        #   brew reinstall opencv --HEAD --qith-qt
        self.__setupWindow()

    # Set camera resolution. The max resolution is webcam dependent
    # so change it to a resolution that is both supported by your camera
    # and compatible with your monitor
    def __setupCamera(self):


    def __setupWindow(self):
        cv2.namedWindow('frame', cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN)
        cv2.setWindowProperty('frame', cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN, cv2.WINDOW_FULLSCREEN)

    def update(self):
        ret, frame = self.cam.read()
        cv2.imshow('frame', frame)

    def release(self):
        self.cam.release()


    def read(self):
        ret, frame = self.cam.read()
        return cv2.flip(frame, 1)

    def update(self):
        cv2.imshow('frame', self.read())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    mirror = Mirror()
    while True:
        mirror.update()
        if cv2.waitKey(1) == 27:
            break
    mirror.release()
```

Script 2 also works like charm in separate window. But to combine them, I got error and replacing mirror output in the video output.

Comment: Nice project! Welcome to Stackoverflow. If I get you right you have two questions. I recommend to only ask one question in one post. Try to reduce each problem to a minimal reproducible example and explain exactly what you need. If you are asking for error messages then please add the messages and stack traces and the code that produces the error. Please check the tag names if they really address your question (your tag `mirror` seems to be misleading). All this will make it more probable that you receive helpful answers. Please read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to replace the following lines in script 1:

```
while True:
   success, img = video.read()
   img = detector.findHands(img)
```

with:

```
while True:
   success, img = video.read()
   img = cv2.flip(img, 1) 
   img = detector.findHands(img)
```

If its the wrong "flip" check the docu for the options [here](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#gaca7be533e3dac7feb70fc60635adf441)
or use the transpose function [here](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga46630ed6c0ea6254a35f447289bd7404)

Comment: Thanks for reply, somehow the problem did not fixed completely. The image is now shown correctly with cv.flip function. But the camera still detect my hand same as previous one. So I think the inverted camera is the key to fixed with.

Comment: okay, so just a half fix, its little bit against my expectations, because the detection should  work on the flipped img, whats about changing the label printing offset calculation in function : drawAll or in the loop: 'for button in buttonList' ?

Answer (score 0):

You may have omitted a part of script 2, so I merged script 1 and script 2 according to my understanding, I hope it will be helpful.

First, you need to initialize the videocapture:

```py
def __setupCamera(self):
    self.cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    self.cam.set(3, 1280)
    self.cam.set(4, 720)
    self.finalText = ""
```

As `main` shown:

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    mirror = Mirror()
    while True:
        mirror.update()
        if cv2.waitKey(1) == 27:
            break
    mirror.release()
```

only the `update` is called(you should keep only one `update`), and `read` is called in `update`, so add `find hand` in `read`:

```py
def read(self):
    ret, img = self.cam.read()
    img = cv2.flip(img, 1)
    img = detector.findHands(img)
    lmList, bboxInfo = detector.find
    img = drawAll(img, buttonList)
    if lmList:
    ...
    ...
```